# hi every one there is a question reading kyma integration with btp sap Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, kyma

While enabling the kyma(enable Kyma) in the btp trial its asking for the some details like clientID and issuer URL  and this are the mandatory fields.
can any one worked on this kyma enable form then provide the solution.

Which url we have to provide in that I have tried with my kyma URL but its not working.
"http://localhost:3001/cluster/k3d-kyma/overview" as it is mentioned that it should be in the form of https schema.